# blog_id в WP после смены блога

Tags: wordpress

Я записываю в переменную старый (текущий) ID блога, переключаюсь на другой блог и понимаю, что в этой переменной храниться уже новый ID, а не предыдущий. Похоже, что переменная является ссылкой на объект. Как решить данный вопрос?

```
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();      // 2
switch_to_blog( 1 );
var_dump($blog_id );                   // 1
```

Comment: Версия вп какая? Поставил самую свежую и такого у меня нет

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решил проблему изменив название переменной с $blog_id на другое. Оказывается в $blog_id храниться как раз информация о текущем блоге.

Answer (score 2):

Не обманывайте людей :) Нахожусь на сайте 2. Код:

```
var_dump( get_current_blog_id() );
switch_to_blog( 1 );
var_dump( get_current_blog_id() );
die();
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы у себя перезаписываете глобальную переменую, а потом тяните из нее данные.

Comment: Ну выглядит логично. Только у меня другой код и выполняет другую функцию.

Comment: blog_id => глобальная переменная вордпресс